# Getting started with sugarORM 1.4

Tags: android, sugarorm

I'm trying to figure out how to use sugarORM (version 1.4, [imported with Gradle](http://satyan.github.io/sugar/getting-started.html#download-sugar)).

I have a simple object with a `public String name` field, among others.

I construct that simple object with that name and save it like this (with `TEST_TYPE` a random String) :

```
    CustomObject type = new CustomObject(TEST_TYPE);
    long l=type.save();
    Toast.makeText(this, "Type ajouté ! id="+l, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

My log is showing id=14 by now, so I assume writing is OK.

But when I want to read, there is no sense :

- `CustomObject.count(CustomObject.class)` returns 14
- `CustomObject.findById(CustomObject.class, 2)` returns null
- `CustomObject.first(CustomObject.class)` returns null
- `CustomObject.find(LifeEventType.class, "NAME = ?", new String[]{TEST_TYPE})` returns null

I don't know if it is related, but I get this exception on warning log : 
`java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> at com.orm.SugarRecord.find(SugarRecord.java:196)` (which is code too advanced for a noob like me...)

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: try another ORM. many people complain that it is slow and "peace of sheet"

Comment: I tried it in my latest project but wasn't very happy and switched to greendao.

Comment: see https://github.com/Raizlabs/AndroidDatabaseLibraryComparison for example

Comment: Wow, that's violent xD ! Thanks, I'm gonna try other libraries. @pskink I don't understand the charts, is it good to be high or low ?

Comment: the lower the better

Comment: @DanChaltiel can you insert the code of the CustomObject ?

Comment: slow, not reliable, dont use this junk

Answer (score 19):

It happens when you don't provide an empty contructor.

SugarORM can correctly save the entities, but can't instantiate them when you try to perform a select query.

The solution is to include an empty constructor and the getters/setters within your entity

```
public CustomObject(){}
```

More documentation [here](http://satyan.github.io/sugar/creation.html)

Comment: +1 Although I read about it in the docs, I later changed one of my constructors, causing this problem. The `NoSuchMethodException` error could've been mentioned in the docs / github page :\